# How to Imgae Url path correct by code for share image on facebook

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, facebook-apps

I'm getting a image path with using this code below:

```
string strUrl = Server.MapPath(Url.ToString());
```

result is bellow:

```
E:\\Projects\\Project\\ProjectFolder\\Ptoject\\Image\\Aliisza.jpg
```

I want to get path like this for share photo on facebook like this

```
http://wwww.domain.com/Image/Aliisza.jpg
```

which can help me to hare Image on facebool with facebook app im doing this code in c# please let me know how can i can make this Image path like I want to hit on facebook for share. give you some sample of code to do this task done. Hope some buddy have a solution to do this task and hit image Url like i want.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all ServerMap path is working fine as expected, it will give rootlevel path.

To get url, you need to append it to the domain name.

What best you can do is put the value in config file and use it.

Also you can try
Directory.GetParent(fileName).FullName;

To get Parent folder name.

This is concept to decide what approach you choose.

Comment: can you give me sample how do this.

Comment: Save http://wwww.domain.com/ in web.config
If you have static folder path, you can even save it to web.config or pull parent folder from code above.
And you have file name
Add above all and you have well formed path